# Using meteor executable inside vagrant machine in webstorm

Tags: meteor, vagrant, webstorm

Hello I would like to make webstorm recognize and organize my code based on my vagrant meteor machine executable, not my windows one. Can I do that? When I go to the config the executable is only visible in the windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately WebStorm doesn’t support running/debugging Meteor remotely.
Please feel free to file a request for this feature to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB